# Nav UL items stretch across page

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm working on a simple static page and almost have my navigation bar right. Right now, the menu items are stretching across the width of the entire nav bar, rather than staying contained in their "list area" if that makes sense. I feel like I've tried everything, and I think it has something to do with the z-index I have on the nav and photo carousel (so that the nav menu items show up on top of the carousel) and the positioning, but I can't figure it out.

[image]

```css
nav ul {
  background: #A6CE4F;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f37b35;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #1f354b;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #e2550e;
}
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav style="position: relative; z-index: 2;">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">ICAB Leadership Group</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Requirements</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Roles & Responsibilities</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Site Cabs</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Community Input</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Cross Network Collaborations</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Community Toolbox</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Community engagement templates and documents</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Network and Community fact sheets</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Training materials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">FAQs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Community Research Resources</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Acronyms</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Email Alias Lists </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">Contacts & Email Lists</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: The test link is http://10.0.11.40/community/ICAB.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because you have width set to 100% to your dropdown ul.

Add a width like this:

```
width: auto;
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fnmbhuet/3/).

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it! I figured it was something super simple that I was missing :)

Comment: But also, why all the space on the right side of the nav bar?

Comment: @LAS87, see my updated fiddle. Is there any space now?

Comment: @lonut yep, still there :(

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have `width: 100%` set to `.nav ul ul`. If you want the width to remain variable, set `width: 100%` to `width: auto` in `.nav ul ul`

Example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaRJXZ